# Capistrano example error- undefined symbol 'map' for :hosts symbol

Tags: ruby, capistrano

I have been trying to run the basic capistrano example, from the link:

https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/2.x-Getting-Started

```
task :search_libs, :hosts => "www.capify.org" do
  run "ls -x1 /usr/lib | grep -i xml"
end
```

I saved in a file called capfile and I do,

```
$ cap capfile
```

And get the following error:

```
➜  capistrano  cap --trace capfile
cap aborted!
NameError: undefined local variable or method `tasks_without_stage_dependency' for #<Capistrano::Application:0x007ff1734c8e40>
/Users/Dhruv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/capistrano-3.2.1/lib/capistrano/application.rb:24:in `top_level_tasks'
/Users/Dhruv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/Users/Dhruv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/Users/Dhruv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/Users/Dhruv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/Users/Dhruv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/Dhruv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/Users/Dhruv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/capistrano-3.2.1/lib/capistrano/application.rb:15:in `run'
/Users/Dhruv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/capistrano-3.2.1/bin/cap:3:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Dhruv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/cap:23:in `load'
/Users/Dhruv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/cap:23:in `<main>'
/Users/Dhruv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/Dhruv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

My ruby version: ruby 2.1.1p76 (2014-02-24 revision 45161) [x86_64-darwin13.0]
Cap version: Capistrano Version: 3.2.1 (Rake Version: 10.2.2)

Answer (score 2):

The documentation you provided is for Capistrano v2, use new one http://capistranorb.com/

In your case, you need step 4 from http://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/preparing-your-application